# Am I eligible for the Eurail Youth pass? I am 27.5 years old

Tags: eurail

I will be 27 years and 5 months old this June, when I'll take the first train. Will I be eligible for the EU rail Youth pass?

It shows **12-27 years** old for Youth, and **28+** for the Adult. I think I fall in between 27 and 28.

Which one should I get?

Comment: If the drinking age is 18, do you think you'd be able to buy alcohol if you're between 17 and 18?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I understand your point. But, there's a clear line in your example, anything below 18 is not eligible, anything above is eligible. If you check here, it's not clearly given what happens to people between 27 and 28.

Comment: You cannot be "between" 27 and 28 years old in this context. When laws or regulations decree that a certain age, in years, provides, or removes, an entitlement or obligation, you reach that age on the appropriate birthday, and you keep that age until your next birthday.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question. I re-asked on https://law.stackexchange.com/q/38255/6859 where it belongs.

Comment: @chx What's the legal aspect? It's a question about eligibility for a particular kind of travel pass, which simply hinges on whether "12-27 years" means "If your age is completed years is between 12 and 27 inclusive" or "If you're between your 12th and 27th birthdays."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Well, I ended up taking the non-youth pass. If you choose the youth pass, they won't let you choose your birth date in the calendar, if you are more than 27 years old at the time of booking.

So, I conclude that you have to be less than or exactly equal to 27 years to book the youth pass. If you are even a day older than 27 years, you won't be even able to book it in the website.

Notice that I am not able to select Jan 7, 1992 in the following page (Traveller details).
[image]

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Check the screenshot. I tried again, and took a screenshot. When I reach the Traveller details page this comes up.