# Can I buy ticket for 12-25y.o when I am still under 26?

Tags: tickets

Can I buy ticket for 12-25 year old when I am still under 26?
There is no this info on the website I want to purchase from.
It is Rhone express (Lyon, France)

Comment: This question is pretty relevant, then https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134011/am-i-eligible-for-the-eurail-youth-pass-i-am-27-5-years-old

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the answers to [this question,](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134011/am-i-eligible-for-the-eurail-youth-pass-i-am-27-5-years-old) in France, as well as in other countries, you are the given age till your next birthday and you can buy and use that 12/25 year old ticket from your 12th birthday till your 26th birthday.
In some cases you can use a multiple day ticket after the given birthday, but in that case it will be mentioned in the rules for the ticket.